# Create the same token for all possible increment expressions

Tags: c#, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I am developing a lexer grammar for C/C++ source code. The goal of the grammar is to fight plagiarism between students at university.

To improve the effectiveness of the grammar, I want ANTLR to create the same token for the 4(?) different ways a student could increment a variable:

```
i++
++i
i += 1
(i = i + 1) [I doubt that this can be solved with ANTLR]
```

Each of these expressions should result in the token INCREMENT.

What I have come up with so far: (only the neccessary parts of the grammar are reproduced here)

```
options {
    language = CSharp3;
    filter = true;
    k = 2;
}

INCREMENT : IDENTIFIER (PLUSPLUS | ADDEQUAL '1') | PLUSPLUS IDENTIFIER ;
IDENTIFIER 
    :   LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT)*;

/*
 * covers both decimal and hex integer literals
 */
INTEGER_LITERAL : 
   DIGIT+ | '0x' HEX_DIGIT+;

ADDEQUAL            : '+=';
PLUSPLUS            : '++';

fragment
LETTER  :   'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z';

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : DIGIT | 'a'..'f' | 'A'..'F';

fragment
DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

testing this grammar for `i += 1` results in the token sequence `IDENTIFIER ADDEQUAL INTEGER_LITERAL` instead of `INCREMENT`.

Why is that? 
From my understanding the precedence of rules is top to bottom plus `INCREMENT` is the "bigger" rule.

What adjustments to the grammar need I make to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> testing this grammar for `i += 1` results in the token sequence `IDENTIFIER ADDEQUAL INTEGER_LITERAL` instead of `INCREMENT`.
>
> Why is that?

Because `"i += 1"` contains spaces you didn't account for inside your `INCREMENT` rule.

> What adjustments to the grammar need I make to get the desired result?

Account for the spaces (and line breaks, possibly).

However, creating a lexer alone does not seem the way to go here. You really need a parser, IMO. And the option `k = 2;` sets look ahead for parser rules, not lexer rules: so in case you stick to lexing only, you mind as well remove it.

Comment: holy sh*t. Thank you. That was incredibly dumb and probably the sign to quit for today